# Convert floating point number to a certain precision, and then copy to string

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have a floating point number, say `135.12345678910`. I want to concatenate that value to a string, but only want `135.123456789`. With print, I can easily do this by doing something like:

```
print "%.9f" % numvar
```

with `numvar` being my original number. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: % exactly does that - % is not part of the print function but of string - see [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Answer (score 250, accepted):

With Python < 3 (e.g. 2.6 [see comments] or 2.7), there are two ways to do so.

```
# Option one
older_method_string = "%.9f" % numvar

# Option two
newer_method_string = "{:.9f}".format(numvar)
```

But note that for Python versions above 3 (e.g. 3.2 or 3.3), option two is [preferred](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

For more information on option two, I suggest [this link on string formatting from the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

And for more information on option one, [this link will suffice and has info on the various flags](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Python 3.6 (officially released in December of 2016), added the `f` string literal, [see more information here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), which extends the `str.format` method (use of curly braces such that `f"{numvar:.9f}"` solves the original problem), that is,

```
# Option 3 (versions 3.6 and higher)
newest_method_string = f"{numvar:.9f}"
```

solves the problem. Check out @Or-Duan's answer for more info, but this method is *fast*.

Comment: option two should be `newer_method_string = "{:.9f}".format(numvar)` - note the required `:` to separate the field and the formatting. I have tested this on 2.7.5 anyway.

Comment: For python 2.6 option two should be `newer_method_string = "{0:.9f}".format(numvar)` -- note the required 0 for the field_name for this older version.

Comment: I want significant figures not just truncating blindly t according to `{v.:3f}`. How do I get significant figures?

Comment: @CharlieParker I'd recommend using exponential notation, for example `{:12.5e}`. There's more in this subsection of the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Answer (score 78):

## Python 3.6

Just to make it clear, you can use [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) formatting. This has almost the same syntax as the `format` method, but make it a bit nicer.

Example:

```
print(f'{numvar:.9f}')
```

More reading about the new f string:

- *[What's new in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)* (same link as above)
- *[PEP official documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)*
- *[Python official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)*
- *[Really good blog post - talks about performance too](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/)*

Here is a diagram of the execution times of the various tested methods (from last link above):

[image: execution times]

Comment: Is there a syntax for specifying accuracy other than 9?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa just change the `9` to any number you want then

Comment: I mean arbitrary accuracy, like `n`

Comment: Do you mean a dynamic number that is being calculated in run time? If so, you will have to use `round`

Answer (score 61):

Using `round`:

```
>>> numvar = 135.12345678910
>>> str(round(numvar, 9))
'135.123456789'
```

Answer (score 13):

In case the precision is not known until runtime, this other formatting option is useful:

```
>>> n = 9
>>> '%.*f' % (n, numvar)
'135.123456789'
```

Comment: If you'd prefer to use `.format`-method, note that this can also be done by nesting arguments like so: `'{:.{n}f}'.format(numvar,n=n)`.

Answer (score 8):

It's not print that does the formatting, It's a property of strings, so you can just use

```
newstring = "%.9f" % numvar
```

Comment: Or use the new style formatting.  valueString ="{:.9f}".format(number)

Answer (score 2):

To set precision with 9 digits, get:

```
print "%.9f" % numvar
```

Return precision with 2 digits:

```
print "%.2f" % numvar
```

Return precision with 2 digits and float converted value:

```
numvar = 4.2345
print float("%.2f" % numvar)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as long as the number of decimals points are in range; After that it depends on the hardware. Beyond 14th decimal place, I could not get it to match. Values from latitude from a digital elevation file

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

```
lat1 = -81.0016666666670072 
lat2 = -81.0016666666670062
assert lat1 == lat2 # no asserion error :(

# try with Decimal
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 16
assert Decimal(lat1) == Decimal(lat2) # no asserion error :(

# Lets see string representation
print(f"{lat1:.16f}", f"{lat2:.16f}")
# -81.0016666666670062 -81.0016666666670062 :( Perils of Float

# Lets see how it is store in hardware
print(lat1.hex(), lat2.hex())
# -0x1.4401b4e81b500p+6 -0x1.4401b4e81b500p+6

# 14-th position it is able to identify 
lat1 = -81.0016666666670162 
lat2 = -81.0016666666670062
#-0x1.4401b4e81b501p+6 -0x1.4401b4e81b500p+6
print(lat1.hex(), lat2.hex())
assert lat1 == lat2 # assertion error :)
```

Answer (score -2):

The `str` function has a bug. Please try the following. You will see '0,196553' but the right output is '0,196554'. Because the `str` function's default value is ROUND_HALF_UP.

```
>>> value=0.196553500000 
>>> str("%f" % value).replace(".", ",")
```

Comment: What is up with `.` vs. `,`? And how is it relevant for pauliwago's question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's a confusing european standard to use a list separator (aka comma: `,`) as a decimal separator I think