# Floating point numbers precision in python

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I have a variable `mn`  whose value is 2.71989011072, I use round function of python to get a precision value of 2.720 but I get 2.72 only

```
mn=2.71989011072
print round(mn,3)
```

Gives 2.72 and not 2.720

Comment: it _is_ exactly 2.72000000000000 (etc.), you're looking for the print statement to format differently?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to get the print statement print 2.720 and not 2.72. Sorry if i confused you

Comment: @WillMolter: It actually isn't - the number represented in decimal by 2.72 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point.

Comment: I just glanced at `round` figuring it gives a float, which would imply my comment, oops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the *print* function apply a second rounding.

```
mn = 2.71989011072
mn = round(mn, 3)
print(mn)
```

You'll get:

```
2.72
```

You need to use a formatted string:

```
print("{0:.3f}".format(mn))
```

You'll get:

```
2.720
```

Notice that the formatted string can do the rounding for you.
With this, you'll get the same output:

```
mn = 2.71989011072
print("{0:.3f}".format(mn))
# => 2.720
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263597/convert-floating-point-number-to-certain-precision-then-copy-to-string

Answer (score 1):

Function rounds it to three first digits which correctly results in 2.72. The zeros are matter of printing ans string formatting, not rounding.

To print it with three zeros you will need to do the following:

```
print '{0:.3f}'.format(round(mn, 3))
```

That will round number first and then print it, formatting it with three zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You desire a particular string representation of the number, not another number.

Use `format()` instead of `round()`:

```
>>> mn = 2.71989011072
>>> format(mn, '.3f')
'2.720'
```

Answer (score 0):

with python 3, we can use f strings

```py
print(f"{mn:.3f}")
```

> 2.720